# Why does not selenium test work on Jenkins while successfully working local?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, intellij-idea

I've a test suite that includes bunch of BDD tests which has been implemented by using selenium lib. I've also used [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) for Selenium WebDriver binaries. Tests work successfully on local. The test codes are on git also, and there is an environment which is built by using git-bitbucket-jenkins-jira-nexus and etc. Additionally, this environment is not in my local, is on the server that located in another country.

So these tests have to work successfully on Jenkins. However, I get an error over Jenkins when i run the test via Jenkins and the error is

> Could not initialize class io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager

This lib has been added to the project repository(nexus) in the environment. When I remove credentials of the remote repository from `settings.xml`, the error is

> missing class io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager"

That means, Jenkins can reach the repository. But why can't this lib be initialized on Jenkins whereas can be initialize on local?

I've also tried that work on local by connecting remote repository to understand that the source of this issue is related with differences between version of lib in local and version of lib in repo. However It doesn't work. Intellij Idea just checks `pom.xml` for indexed maven repositories. I think, It should check `setting.xml` also, because I've set credentials(URL, id username and password) of remote repo within `settings.xml`.

Comment: i did a similar thing not too long ago. i used the firefoxdriver, and i was successful in getting it to work within a jenkins build. i remember, to troubleshoot this, i opened a remote desktop to the jenkins machine. try to build it manually by opening visual studio. if the build is successful, try running your selenium-tests from there. a firefox installation in a compatible version with my driverversion was neccessary on the build server for me.

Comment: @MasterAzazel you've also used WebDriverManager, didn't you? Did I get this right?

Comment: nope i used something like WebDriver xy = new FirefoxDriver();
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/integration-of-jenkins-with-selenium-webdriver/ and from https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp : "Selenium-WebDriver makes direct calls to the browser using each browser’s native support for automation. How these direct calls are made, and the features they support depends on the browser you are using. Information on each ‘browser driver’ is provided later in this chapter." I would try without the WebDriverManager for debugging